# mdc-web Temporary Drawer - close animation

Tags: web, material-components

Comparing `close` at the demo for `Temporary Drawer`
https://material-components-web.appspot.com/drawer/temporary-drawer.html#

With e.g. the Gmail app on Android, the close animation of the `Temporary Drawer` seems different.

---

#### mdc-web 0.10.0

Very fast, nearly instant.

#### Android 6.0.1

Longer duration, more smooth and gentle animation.

---

Both should apply to the Material Design spec. I prefer the android variant, but not that sharp on the spec. Question, is this a bug for the mdc-web or two different interpretations?

Comment: Looks like a bug, the spec states around 200ms. Filed issue on this https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this issue the close animation will be adjusted
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/646